# Как продолжить выполнение скрипта при появлении определённого файла в каталоге? Python

Tags: python, мониторинг

я новичок в программировании и моя проблема такова:
скрипт подключает внешнюю программу, которая формирует файлы в директории, в тот момент, когда программа сформирует файл с расширением .total (он будет один на всю директорию), нужно продолжить выполнение скрипта (перейти к следующим действиям).
Я попытался воспользоваться модулем `watchdog` для мониторинга изменений файловой системы. Моя идея заключалась в следующем (код ниже):

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        if 'total' in event.src_path:
            return # Универсальная команда

observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(Handler(), Dir_path, recursive=True)
observer.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
except: # Какая-то универсальная команда для остановки цикла, переданная из функции класса
    observer.stop()
    observer.join()

# Дальнейшие действия
```

Пока не силён в классах и не особо понял методы работы модуля `watchdog`, поэтому буду благодарен за советы по реализации моей задачи (необязательно используя этот модуль).

Comment: В чём собственно у вас вопрос? Скрипт ваш работает или нет? Если не работает - какую ошибку выдаёт или в чём это выражается? Так то я только вижу, что у `except` не хватает двоеточия в конце - оно попало внутрь комментария.

Comment: @CrazyElf нет он не работает, так как я именно в данном алгоритме не могу понять, что можно использовать вместо "# Универсальная команда" для того, чтобы прервать бесконечный цикл, остановить обсёрвера и продолжить выполнять код
UPD Исправил поле кода для лучшего понимания вопроса

Comment: А, понял. Ну вообще по-хорошему вы должны делать нужный функционал внутри `on_created`. Как нормально прервать обсервер изнутри `FileSystemEventHandler`, я что-то с ходу не нашёл. Можно какой-нибудь `signal` из треда обсервера, наверное, передать в основной тред. Но как-то это всё не выглядит правильно, наверное есть более корректный шаблон однократного ожидания создания файла.

Comment: @CrazyElf Скорее всего нормальный шаблон имеется, но по похожим запросам я встречал лишь совет использовать модуль `watchdog`. Этот участок кода по факту был заимствован из тех ответов и немного адаптирован под мою задачу. Я даже не уверен, имеет ли данный модуль функционал для того, чтобы корректно её реализовать, но альтернатив я пока не нашёл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Передал observer, чтобы остановить его. Да, можно потом еще обработать try, чтобы не вылезали всякие KeyboardInterrupt, но и так вроде работает.

Что может не работать здесь? Смотри, когда ты создаешь файл руками, то создается файл с именем "новый файл" (по крайней мере на линуксе так, у тебя может сработает), а только потом он переименовывается в "name.total", поэтому нужно обрабатывать изменение в имени.

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import os
import time

Dir_path = os.getcwd()

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        
    def on_created(self, event):
        if event.src_path.endswith('.total'):
            self.parent.stop()

observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(Handler(observer), Dir_path, recursive=True)
observer.start()
while observer.should_keep_running():
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Нужно дописать в Handler метод

```
def on_modify(self, event):
    pass
```

В чем может быть тут проблема - почему-то отслеживается не файл, а путь к нему, крайняя директория, так что вообще без понятия, как отследить переименование.

Comment: Так и отслеживайте файл, передайте обсерверу сразу имя файла, а не просто каталог

Comment: Так файл только создан

Comment: @handowl спасибо, вроде всё заработало. По поводу переименования после создания: у меня, если выводить события, `Handler` уведомляет именно о создании файла с данным расширением, так что с этим проблем не должно возникнуть. Единственное, не могли бы Вы для лучшего моего понимания работы с классами пояснить, что означает функция `__init__` и параметр `parent` в ней, а также куда именно мы передаём `observer`  в классе и почему в описании класса у нас стоит `FileSystemEventHandler`, а при его вызове (или как это правильно назвать) стоит `observer`, буду благодарен.

Comment: __init__  - это метод (функция класса в терминах ООП), который вызывается при создании объекта какого-то класса, так сказать инициализации (но вообще инстанцирования). То есть, создавая объект класса Собака, Вы вызываете сначала этот метод. В нем можно наделять конкретную собаку какими-то свойствами. Но это не совсем конструктор (метод в ООП, вызываемый при создании объекта). ````init```` нужен для большей гибкости.

Comment: Далее, ````FileSystemEventHandler```` - это базовый класс, наследуясь от которого, Вы описываете свой новый класс. Можно не наследоваться, но будет больше кода, Вы будете писать то, что уже написано, да и вообще наследование - не всегда плохо. Конкретно - это выглядит так: Собака(Животное). Скажем, есть животные, есть класс Животное, мы хотим описать абстрактную собаку, чтобы потом создать конкретную собаку.

Comment: Для создания же объекта (это процесс инстанцирования) - то есть какого-то конкретного экземпляра класса в Python, как и во многих, если не во всех языках, необходимо написать название класса и скобки. В некоторых языках это сразу вызовет конструктор (помним, это функция). Как и при работе с любой функцией, необходимо в скобках передать аргумент. В данном случае мы сразу передаем ````observer````, который надо будет потом убить.
Чем это отличается от описания класса и ````FileSystemEventHandler```` в скобках - во втором случае это синтаксис наследования в Python

Comment: При вызове ````init```` метода, передается ````observer````. который надо убить. ````self```` - это ссылка на сам экземпляр, для того чтобы указывать, у какого объекта мы хотим менять атрибуты и вообще с каким мы работаем.

Comment: @handowl премного благодарен за объяснения